# Mouse move choppy and laggy with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, dell-inspiron, ubuntu-unity

I installed Ubuntu LTS 11.04 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell M5030. My mouse moves choppy and laggy.

I do not encounter this problems on Ubuntu 10.04 on this machine.

I think this bug may com from Unity. But I am not sure how to fix this problem.
Could anyone help me solve this problem or suggest ways to fix it?

May be I missed a important thing in my question. In my case, there are no lag memory problems when use. If i use my touch-pad, mouse cursor move normally. It seems to happen with all my usb mouse.

Comment: You might try exploring the Ubuntu exchange. A very similar question to this was asked there.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/133181/ubuntu-12-04-x64-very-slow-response-and-sluggishness

Have you tried that fix?

Comment: Thanks you, Sunny. However, in my case, there are no lag memory problems when use. May be I missed a important thing in my question. If i use my touch-pad, mouse cursor move normally. It seems to happen with all my usb mouse.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience 90% of such issues is resolved by **deactivating various desktop visual effects**. Some of them may consume enormous part of your laptop's resources.

Depending on Ubuntu version or desktop settings, try the following actions:

- Un-check all Compiz effects
- Disable Unity or switch from Unity 3D to 2D at least

...and you'll probably observe a significant performance's increase. Then you'll be able to activate whatever you really want (and to observe which function causes the problem in your specific case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in my case, there are no lag memory problems when use. May be I missed a important thing in my question. If i use my touch-pad, mouse cursor move normally. It seems to happen with all my usb mouse. Maybe i need to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Go to GRUB screen on boot select linux version, press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit and type `apci=off` after `ro    quiet`. I don't remember how to make it permanent.